# What kind of DataBase is suitable for high speed USB insertion?

Tags: database, usb

I am building a C# desktop app which intakes data from a USB that wires to multiple transducers (sensors/devices),  e.g. temperature, dimension, humidity etc.  Each devices/sensor sends data real time to the computer concurrently, in very high sampling rate (>1000/s) and inserts to a corresponding database table (e.g. temperature data stored to temperature table etc).

Which kind of database is good for such application, preferably open source? MySQL? SQLite? 
Also what kind of configuration I will need to do to my Database to avoid data lost during high speed data insertion?

Comment: The first question you need to ask yourself is: do you really need to store all that data? With more than 1000 samples per second (which most databases can easily handle given a fast machine) I wonder if aggregate values are an option.

Comment: unfortunately I will need all data to the stored, in real time. My worry is there is multiple devices and multiple threads of data of inserting to the database concurrently, I'm not sure if any database can handle that...

Comment: it depends on the database, but any proper database has support for lazy writes. For PostgreSQL for example: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-SYNCHRONOUS-COMMIT
You only have to worry about the raw throughput of your disks as long as your writes are buffered.

Comment: to prove my point, I just did a test using PostgreSQL on my workstation. Inserting 1,000,000 rows took 9.851 seconds. So that's an average of over 100,000 rows per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you had a look at db40, its Open Source object database designed for what you are doing.

http://www.db4o.com/

Its available for Java & .Net & has heaps of examples, ZERO config (new database(fileName)). If db4o is unable to keep up with the insertion rate (which is unlikely but you never know) you could keep a cache in memory of objects to insert (i.e. cache in memory if db write is to slow and pop items off stack on successful write).

I have used VistaDB (paid .net file database) which is good, not sure about the high levels of insertion but if you cache in memory to a stack I guess you could experiment with different database providers without having to rework to much code.

Another alternative would be a logging solution like log4net, just writing to files but may be worth concidering.